# Set Custom Video Storage Path

Tags: android

I'm having trouble understanding which exact part of the code I would change to set a custom file storage path. This activity successfully brings up the android camera app, lets you take a video and then returns to the activity saying Video Saved To: "File:///storage/emulated/0/videoapp/examplevideoname.mp4"

I just want to save it to a different folder of my choosing, but this is from the google tutorial and I can't figure out which part I need to change:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

All help seriously appreciated! The google code is even commented to help, but I'm new enough that it's still not clear to me.

It's obvious to me that "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory" has something to do with it, but I can't figure out if I'm supposed to replace that part with my new path or something else.

Here are the code snippets:

onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    //create new Intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);  // create a file to save the video
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  // set the image file name

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // set the video image quality to high

    // start the Video Capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Video captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the video capture
        } else {
            // Video capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
}
```

getOutputMediaFile:

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
  if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own folder then you have to changed here

```
 File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
```

Where,  "MyCameraApp" is your folder name so you can replace with your folder and Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) This is your directory, If you want to save only sdcard then replace with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory. It's create a folder in /sdcard/your_folder_name/your_video_file.mp4